# Face issue in App Thinning Option for Distribution Xcode 10.2.1

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode10.2.1

Facing issue when trying to make archive for distribution with syntax swift 5 , Xcode 10.2.1, I am not able to see **App Thinning** Dropdown in that window. I am already done the required setup for the App Thinning in my project.

In below step i can't find Dropdown from which i can select option for the same.

[image]

Comment: you need to chose Ad Hoc, Enterprise and Development